# Having trouble populating mongoose schema.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting my array of nested objects to populate. I understand the populate method somewhat but I'm not sure how to properly write the correct code for this api call, specifically populating nested objects. I don't have much experience with Node.Js or mongoose so I'm thankful for any help or tips you give me.

Here is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostsOfTheWeekSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sunday: {
        posts: [{}],
        date: Date
    },
    monday: {
        posts: [{}],
        date: Date
    },
    tuesday: {
        posts: [{}],
        date: Date
    },
    wednesday: {
        posts: [{}],
        date: Date
    },
    thursday: {
        posts: [{}],
        date: Date
    },
    friday: {
        posts: [{}],
        date: Date
    },
    saturday: {
        posts: [{}],
        date: Date
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PostsOfTheWeek', PostsOfTheWeekSchema);
```

Here is my api call:

```
router.get('/postsOfTheDay', function (req, res, next) {
    PostsOfTheWeek.find({}).populate({path: 'posts', populate: {path: 'post', model: 'Post'}}).exec(function (err, posts) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        res.json(posts);
    });
});
```

and here is my response from the api call:

```
{
"_id": "599a5a529f5cee12bbeb7737",
"__v": 0,
"saturday": {
"posts": [],
},
"friday": {
"posts": [],
},
"thursday": {
"posts": [],
},
"wednesday": {
"posts": [],
},
"tuesday": {
"posts": [],
},
"monday": {
"posts": [],
},
"sunday": {
"date": "2017-08-21T03:58:10.000Z",
"posts": [
  {
"name": "Music",
"post": "599a298f5bdc6e107a8a5a48"
},
  {
"name": "News",
"post": "599a134189c3150fe701d384"
}
],
}
}
```

I can't seem to populate the post property. Any help or tips are welcome, thank you for reading.

Comment: `PostsOfTheWeek.find({}, function(err, posts){ console.log(posts)})` try this to see what's stored in posts then we'll move from there

Comment: You don't seem to understand what "populate" means here. Your model is "embedded" and "population" refers to "taking items from a related collection". Embedded means that there is "no relation" because you are not pointing to references in another collection. So the only things that will be in the "embedded" arrays is what you actually put in the document. Since you "don't know this well" you would probably do better to take this back a step and describe what it is you are expecting to achieve as a result, and for what purpose.